# Trouble ignoring column prompts if left blank

Tags: obiee

I have a dashboard containing 2 analysis reports. The reports are nearly identical (one is being used as a reference to a system we are trying to retire), and so they use the same prompt columns.

The problem I am running into is if I leave any of the prompts columns blank, the dashboard prompt still expects a value, causing the report to return nothing.

```
Dealer Number is equal to Prompt_Dealer   -Left default blank in the analysis
and     Enterprise is equal to {}         -Added {} to the default analysis value
and     Dealer Name is equal to ""        -Added "" to the default analysis value
```

I've also tried using null, but with no luck.

Is there a way to ignore the column prompt if I don't enter a value on the dashboard page?

Comment: Do you have these prompts set to require user input or no?

Comment: Mark - They are not set to require user input. I may have figured out a solution, set analysis filters to OR (in a group) instead of AND. After testing several combinations it appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the individual analysis filters to OR, instead of AND, and making sure that they are logically grouped, the dashboard prompts will be ignored when left blank.